# How To Add MarVoSym Font to Context on Windows ?

Tags: fonts, context, windows

I have context source file containing

```
\definefont[Dings][name:MarVoSym]
```

and I import it via \input .

When I run **context** on my source, I always get

```
! Font \**Dings**:=MarVoSym at 11.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
```

I wish I could recall how I made it working on Linux but this machine is **Windows with fresh TexLive 2010 installation** and I am kind of confused what to do.

Comment: The easiest solution will be to add the font to `$OSFONTDIR`. Does TL2010 add `C:\Windows\Fonts` to `OSFONTDIR`? If so, intall the font as you would normally do in Windows, and then run `mtxrun --script font --reload`. After that ConTeXt should be able to find the font.

Comment: Where is / should be $OSFONTDIR set ? I've already installed the font but that alone is not enough. As for mtxrun, I'm getting some message : MTXrun | unknown script 'font.lua' or 'mtx-font.lua'.

Comment: Run `mtxrun --generate` and then try `mtxrun --script`. `OSFONTDIR` s set in either `texmf.cnf` or texmfcnf.lua` located under `$TEXMF/web2c/`. You can see the list of all variables using `mtxrun --variables` (not sure if TL2010 supports that).

Comment: BTW, since you are using a fresh install, I would suggest using ConTeXt minimals rather than texlive. The minimals can be installed in parallel to texlive, so you can still use texlive for latex. The advantage is the the minimals are better tuned for context (and are also updated more frequently, typically 3-4 times a week).

Comment: Installation of ConTeXt minimals failed on my box, therefore I'm trying the oh-so-big TeX live :)

Comment: No mtxrun but luatools have the described parameters --generate and  --variables. After running `luatools --generate` I was able to run mtxrun script.

In  `texmf\web2c\texmfcnf.lua` I have only this:
'return {
  TEXMFCACHE = '~/.texlive2010/texmf-var'
}'

Comment: I don't know if the reload was succesfull, I see this in output:

`MTXrun | fontnames: 451 files rejected due to clashes
MTXrun | fontnames: 503 double lookups in mappings
MTXrun | fontnames: 12 double lookups in fallbacks`


I have `OSFONTDIR=$SystemRoot/fonts//`. I'm not sure what is $SystemRoot, but I have the font instaleld in system - in `C:\Windows\Fonts` I see "MarVoSym Regular".

Comment: I would suggest moving this to the context mailing list. The format of this forum is not well suited for debugging installation problems.